# Hacer una selección múltiple para agregar los datos a una Base de Datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

tengo un código PHP y HTML que representa un formulario, cada vez que se ejecute el botón de guardar el formulario los datos se registran en una base de datos. Mi problema viene de un/unos valor/es, es decir, quiero hacer un select></select con varias opciones y agregar todas estas a la base de datos pero no sé como hacerlo. El campo que necesito que se mande es clave foránea de mi tabla y solo se registra el última valor de mi que escojo. Este es mi código.

```
<?php session_start();

if($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 AND $_SESSION['rol'] != 2){
header("location: ./");
}
include "../conexion.php";

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $alert = '';
        if(empty($_POST['dni']) || empty($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['telefono']) || empty($_POST['direccion']) || empty($_POST['localidad'])  || empty($_POST['provincia']) || empty($_POST['pais']) || empty($_POST['cantidad']) || empty($_POST['precio']) || empty($_POST['totalfactura']))
        {
            $alert='<p class="msg_error">LOS CAMPOS SON OBLIGATORIOS, POR FAVOR RELLÉNELOS</p>';
            echo $alert;
        }else{
            $dni = $_POST['dni'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
            $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
            $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
            $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
            $pais = $_POST['pais'];
            //$nfacturac = $_POST['nfacturac'];
            $nomcomponente = $_POST['nomcomponente'];
            $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
            $precio = $_POST['precio'];
            //$iva = $_POST['iva'];
            $totalfactura = $_POST['totalfactura'];
            $pagada = $_POST['pagada'];
            $nombrecomponente = $_POST['nombrecomponente'];
            $usuario = $_SESSION['idusuario'];


                $insertardatos = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturacliente(dni, nombre, telefono, direccion, localidad, provincia, pais, nomcomponente, cantidad, precio, totalfactura, pagada, nombrecomponente, usuario) VALUES('$dni', '$nombre', '$telefono','$direccion','$localidad','$provincia','$pais','$nomcomponente','$cantidad','$precio','$totalfactura','$pagada', $nombrecomponente, '$usuario')");
                if($insertardatos){
                    $alert = '<p class="msg_save">LOS DATOS SE REGISTRARON</p>';
                    echo $alert;
                }else{
                    $alert = '<p class="msg_error">ERROR AL CREAR EL COMPONENTE</p>';
                    echo $alert;
                }
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($conection);

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
    <title>Nueva Factura</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    <section id="container">
        <div class="title_page">
            <h1>Nueva Factura</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="datos_cliente">
            <div class="action_cliente">
                <h4>Datos del Cliente</h4>
                <a href="registro_cliente.php" class="btn-new btn_new_cliente">Nuevo Cliente</a>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST" name="form_new_cliente_venta" id="form_new_cliente_venta" class="datos">

                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>DNI</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni">
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required><!--Está desactivado-->
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Teléfono</label>
                    <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono"  required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Dirección</label>
                    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="dir_cliente" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Localidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Provincia</label>
                    <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>País</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais" required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="wd100">
                    <label>Numero de Factura</label>
                    <input type="number" name="num_cliente" id="num_cliente" required>
                </div>-->
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Componente</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nomcomponente" id="nomcomponente" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Nombre Componente</label>
                    <?php
                    include("../conexion.php");
                    $descripcion = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM componentes");
                    mysqli_close($conection);
                    $resultadorol = mysqli_num_rows($descripcion);//para ver cuantas filas nos devuelve

                ?>
                <select name="nombrecomponente" id="nombrecomponente" multiple >
                    <?php
                        if($resultadorol > 0 )
                        {
                            while ($nombrecomponente = mysqli_fetch_array($descripcion)) {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $nombrecomponente["codcomponente"]; ?>"><?php echo $nombrecomponente["descripcion"] ?></option>
                    <?php
                                # code...
                            }
                        }
                    ?>

                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Precio</label>
                    <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="wd100">
                    <label>IVA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="iva_cliente" id="iva_cliente" required>
                </div>-->
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Precio Total</label>
                    <input type="text" name="totalfactura" id="totalfactura" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>PAGADA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pagada" id="pagada" required>
                </div>

<input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn_save">

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="datos_venta">
            <h4>Datos Factura</h4>
            <div class="datos">
                <div class="wd50">
                    <label>Vendedor</label>
                    <p>Manuel Márquez Barragán</p>
                </div>
                <div class="wd50">
                    <label>Acciones</label>
                    <div id="acciones_venta">
                        <a href="lista_factura.php" class="btn_ok textcenter" id="btn_anular_venta">Anular</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <?php include "includes/footer.php" ?>
</body>
</html>
```

No sé si mi problema viene del código o de que es una clave foráneo u otra opción que no se me ocurre.

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

Comment: Intenta agregar `[]` al `name="nombrecomponente"`

Comment: : conversión de matriz a cadena en C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php en la línea 33

Error fatal : mysqli_sql_exception no detectado: columna desconocida 'Array' en 'field list' en C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\ sistema\nuevafactura.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php(33): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO fac...') #1 {main } lanzado en C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php en la línea 33
Ese es el error que me da si agrego eso @alanfcm

Comment: Ya lo intenté de esa forma pero no entiendo el error que me da, la linea 33 es:
$insertardatos = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturacliente(dni, nombre, telefono, direccion, localidad, provincia, pais, nomcomponente, cantidad, precio, totalfactura, pagada, nombrecomponente, usuario) VALUES('$dni', '$nombre', '$telefono','$direccion','$localidad','$provincia','$pais','$nomcomponente','$cantidad','$precio','$totalfactura','$pagada', $nombrecomponente, '$usuario')");

Comment: A ver, imagínate que escogen dos o mas componentes... ¿como quieres guardarlos en la base de datos si solo tienes un campo llamado "nombrecomponente" (que además no es cierto, pues lo que tu guardas es el código de componente)?

Comment: Opciones: 1) Insertar un registro en la tabla **facturacliente** por cada nombre de componente (mala idea, pues se repiten todos los demas datos y saldrian varios numeros de factura) 2) Serializar los nombrecomponentes en valores separados por comas, por ejemplo, con los códigos `0145,9999,2342` (no tan mala idea, pero poco práctico si se desea buscar después) 3) Crear una tabla aparte que relacione factura-componentes y alli insertarlos (más práctico, pero hay que crear esa tabla y modificar las inserciones, consiguiendo primero el numero de factura y despues inserrtarlo en esa tabla)

Comment: ¿Cual prefieres?  ¿o como pensabas que tenian que guardarse esos códigos de componente si eran varios?

Comment: Pues me parece interesante y óptima la tercera opción

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137065/discussion-between-manuel-marquez-barragan-and-masterguru).

Comment: Pues ponte a ello. Pasos: 1) Crear una tabla con los campos siguientes: id (clave autoincremental), numfactura, codigo_componente, y establece un índide UNIQUE entre numfactura y codigo_componente para que no se dupliquen cosas sin querer. 2) Eliminar las columnas/campos nomcomponente y nombrecomponente de la tabla facturacliente. Tu haz eso y después te daremos la respuesta para agregar los datos en ambas tablas correctamente (si es que no sabes hacerlo tu ahora)

Comment: Perdón por no contestar antes no me salió la notificación, ya he hecho esos pasos que me dijiste

Comment: Pues ahora revisa mi respuesta e intenta adaptarla a tu nueva tabla con sus nombres de tabla y campos correctos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si has creado la nueva tabla que relaciona facturas y componentes, esto seria la forma de incluir los datos en ambas:

```php
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 AND $_SESSION['rol'] != 2){
    header("location: ./");
}
include "../conexion.php";

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $campos = [
        'dni',
        'nombre',
        'telefono',
        'direccion',
        'localidad',
        'provincia',
        'pais',
        // 'nfacturac',
        // 'nomcomponente'
        'cantidad',
        'precio',
        // 'iva',
        'totalfactura',
    ];
    $alert = '';
    foreach ($campos as $campo) {
        if (empty($_POST[$campo])) {
            $alert = '<p class="msg_error">LOS CAMPOS SON OBLIGATORIOS, POR FAVOR RELLÉNELOS</p>';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($alert)) {
        echo $alert;
    } else {
        // campos comunes
        foreach ($campos as $campo) {
            ${$campo} = $_POST[$campo];
        }
        // otros campos
        $pagada             = $_POST['pagada'];
        $nombrecomponente   = $_POST['nombrecomponente'];
        $usuario            = $_SESSION['idusuario'];

        $insertardatos = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturacliente(dni, nombre, telefono, direccion, localidad, provincia, pais, cantidad, precio, totalfactura, pagada, usuario) VALUES('$dni', '$nombre', '$telefono','$direccion','$localidad','$provincia','$pais','$cantidad','$precio','$totalfactura','$pagada', '$usuario')");

        if ($insertardatos) {
            // insertamos los componentes
            $num_Factura = mysqli_insert_id($conection);
            foreach($nombrecomponente as $codigo_componente) {
                $insertarcomponentes = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturaComponentes(numfactura, codigo_componente) VALUES('$num_Factura', '$codigo_componente')");
            }
            $alert = '<p class="msg_save">LOS DATOS SE REGISTRARON</p>';
            echo $alert;
        }else{
            $alert = '<p class="msg_error">ERROR AL CREAR EL COMPONENTE</p>';
            echo $alert;
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($conection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
    <title>Nueva Factura</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    <section id="container">
        <div class="title_page">
            <h1>Nueva Factura</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="datos_cliente">
            <div class="action_cliente">
                <h4>Datos del Cliente</h4>
                <a href="registro_cliente.php" class="btn-new btn_new_cliente">Nuevo Cliente</a>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST" name="form_new_cliente_venta" id="form_new_cliente_venta" class="datos">
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>DNI</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni">
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required><!--Está desactivado-->
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Teléfono</label>
                    <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono"  required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Dirección</label>
                    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="dir_cliente" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Localidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Provincia</label>
                    <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>País</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais" required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="wd100">
                    <label>Numero de Factura</label>
                    <input type="number" name="num_cliente" id="num_cliente" required>
                </div>-->
                <!--
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Componente</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nomcomponente" id="nomcomponente" required>
                </div>
                -->
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Nombre Componente</label>
                    <?php
                    include("../conexion.php");
                    $descripcion = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM componentes");
                    mysqli_close($conection);
                    $resultadorol = mysqli_num_rows($descripcion);//para ver cuantas filas nos devuelve

                ?>
                <select name="nombrecomponente[]" id="nombrecomponente" multiple >
                    <?php
                        if($resultadorol > 0 ) {
                            while ($nombrecomponente = mysqli_fetch_array($descripcion)) {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $nombrecomponente["codcomponente"]; ?>"><?php echo $nombrecomponente["descripcion"] ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Precio</label>
                    <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="wd100">
                    <label>IVA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="iva_cliente" id="iva_cliente" required>
                </div>-->
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Precio Total</label>
                    <input type="text" name="totalfactura" id="totalfactura" required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>PAGADA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pagada" id="pagada" required>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn_save">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="datos_venta">
            <h4>Datos Factura</h4>
            <div class="datos">
                <div class="wd50">
                    <label>Vendedor</label>
                    <p>Manuel Márquez Barragán</p>
                </div>
                <div class="wd50">
                    <label>Acciones</label>
                    <div id="acciones_venta">
                        <a href="lista_factura.php" class="btn_ok textcenter" id="btn_anular_venta">Anular</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <?php include "includes/footer.php" ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comprueba que te funcione, fíjate en los nombres que he puesto de tabla, etc, para adaptarlo a tu código, y si te funciona me avisas y lo explico un poco.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137188/discussion-on-answer-by-masterguru-hacer-una-seleccion-multiple-para-agregar-los).